# Showing changes on header.phtml only on homepage?

Tags: magento-1.7

So I am adding a feedback widget on the header.phtml file, works fine on the homepage but doesn't show on the other pages. Does anybody know?

Comment: did you clear cache? Also, use template hints to check if it's the same `header.phtml` file on all pages

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: I am testing it on the the default magento theme so the template hints always use the app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml. I am just adding a div below the logo. I think it has to do with the page.xml and that only on the homepage he uses the page/3columns.phtml. Maybe I need to add it for the other templates. hmmm let me try

Comment: very weird, as a test I deleted the logo div, on the homepage the logo is removed, when I go to a category page the logo is still there. Both hints have the same location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using Magento 1.7 so this may not be the same but in 1.9 app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml

There is logic to test for the homepage and load with an `<h1>` and then on non-homepages load it without the `<h1>`.

```
 <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
    <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
  <?php else:?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
  <?php endif?>
```

This could be why your test of removing the logo did not work, perhaps you only removed the first instance and not both of them.  Also check to see that your widget is not being called within only the homepage section.

Comment: Thanks, this helped, did not see there where 2 sections :-)